# javascript not working after click on wire:navigate links

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

In a livewire 3 full-page component I put this javascript code in the app layout to make the sidebar open and close when clicked on it:

```js
const adminHamburger = document.querySelector('#admin-hamburger');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');

adminHamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('translate-x-64');
});
```

It is working as expected but when I click on a `wire:navigate` link, suddenly every js that I wrote on that page does not work anymore.
layout code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
  <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Scripts -->
  @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
  <div class="min-h-screen">
    @include('layouts.back.header')
    @include('layouts.back.sidebar')

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <main>
      {{ $slot }}
    </main>

    @include('layouts.back.footer')

    <script>
      // Runs immediately after Livewire has finished initializing
      // on the page...

      const adminHamburger = document.querySelector('#admin-hamburger');
      const sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');

      adminHamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
        sidebar.classList.toggle('translate-x-64');
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Routing:

```php
Route::get('/admin', App\Livewire\Back\Index::class);
```

It is the link inside the sidebar:

```php
<a wire:navigate href="{{ url('admin') }}" ...>
```

Livewire Index file itself has nothing in it. and it gives me this error:
`Identifier 'adminHamburger' has already been declared at swapCurrentPageWithNewHtml`

Comment: Some HTML and a working snippet including whatever is meant by " a wire:navigate link," might allow us to better assist you here

Comment: FWIW many similar questions - many of those also unanswered due to also not being well asked/reproduceable/full details of issue etc.  Some logic behind a GOOD question vs just an inquery https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also check developer console for any errors being logged.

Comment: it gives me this error: Identifier 'adminHamburger' has already been declared at swapCurrentPageWithNewHtml

Answer (score 0):

I find out that I have to declare variables as `var` in order to make it.

Answer (score 0):

This question really puzzled me; I searched a lot on the internet but I finally found the solution.

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', function(){
document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated',()=>{
     
   const theme = document.getElementById('theme-mode')
   const toggleMenu = document.getElementById('toggleMenu')
   const backdrop = document.getElementById('backdrop')

   theme.addEventListener('click',e=>document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark'))
   toggleMenu.addEventListener('click',e=>{
       document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hidden')
       backdrop.classList.toggle('hidden')
   })

   backdrop.addEventListener('click',e=>{
       document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hidden')
       backdrop.classList.toggle('hidden')
   })
})
})
```